# How to use the round() function in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to know how to use the round() function. In the code, it shows `3.75` for me, but I would like for it to show `4` instead.

My code

```
import random

def dice():

    count = 0
    n = input( "Enter # of dice [3, 6]: " )
    n = int( n )
    diceList = []
    for row in range(0, n):
        diceList.append(random.randint(1, 6))
        count += 1

    print( "\nYou have rolled: ",diceList)

    total=sum(diceList)

    count = round()

    print("The sum is", total, "and the average rounded value is", total / count)


dice()
```

How I want it to look like

```
Enter # of dice [3, 6]: 4

You have rolled: [3, 4, 5, 6]

The sum is 15, and the average rounded value is 4.
```

Comment: What do you think `count = round()` will do? Currently, that function call is missing an argument

Comment: @SuperStormer, I put in ```count = round(total / count)``` at first, but that didn't round for me.

Comment: It should be `count = n` and then you should round it in the print with `round(total/count)`. Or do directly a `round(total/n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you have a `TypeError` because round is called with no args. round takes 1 arg, which is the value to be rounded.

You should change the function's last 2 lines to:

```py
average = round(total/count)
print("The sum is", total, "and the average rounded value is", average)
```

Comment: Thanks so much buddy, this solved for me! I'll accept your answer as soon it allows me.